# How to add baseline prevalence in survival/cumulative incidence curve in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, analysis, survival-analysis

I have a approx. 40 years' follow-up data from a cohort where I want to calculate and plot cumulative incidence of an event (DM) in five groups (Clustnumner) and want to show them in same plot. I have made an initial survival curve using the code 
`fit = survfit(Surv(Folowup_time, DM_inc) ~ as.factor(Clustnumber), data=Co_followUp` and then 
`plot(fit, conf.int=F, xlab = "Time in years", ylab = "Survival probability")` to get the following survival curve. Each line represent one group.
[image]

I converted it to cumulative incidence plot using code `plot(fit, conf.int=F, fun = function(x) 1-x, xlab = "Time in years", ylab = "Cumulative incidence")`and got following plot
[image]

**Question** My question is if for the said event 'DM' that is showing incidence of event over time, I have another column (DM_B) that is also showing it's prevalence at baseline (at follow-up start date) and I want to show that prevalence in the plot e.g., say I don't want my cumulative incidence plot to start from zero and instead I want a line to start from 0.3 to show that 30% individual had prevalent event at baseline when the follow-up started, how do I go with it to get similar graphs? A help will be appreciated as I am really struggling with it :(

Comment: I'm not sure to understand if you're trying to *add another curve to the existing plot* or if you want to modify the values of the current plot with the baseline values. For the first one, just call `lines(x, y, ...)` with the values of columns `DM_B` after the call to `plot` and a curve will be added to the plot.

Comment: @Romain I want to modify the values of the current plot with the baseline values, like it should start at the 0.3 if 30% of my population had event 'DM_B' at baseline and then in curve should show the values of the incident event 'DM' overtime

Comment: I'm not an expert on survival analysis so I'll let others answer on the matter, but I'd say this is something you should do before plotting, that is modifying the model you're fitting by adding baseline data before fiting the survival model, and then the plot will follow accordingly

Comment: @Romain Thank you, this is the thing I am not sure how to add the baseline data before fitting the survival model, will wait for other people maybe

Comment: For this to make sense, you will need to provide group-specific initial prevalences. You also need realize there is no such thing as a “prevalent event”. The words to use might be “prevalence of prior events”.

Comment: Thanks much for the advice @42-  I'll be careful

Comment: I be happy to attempt coding if you provide a [MCVE]. Shouldn’t be too difficult. Four lines of code might make an adequate example.